# Python solving an indentation error

Tags: python

i have written the following code but when i try to run it i get a **File "C:\Users\Moses\Desktop\test.py", line 4
    def deposit(self):
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block** error. i need help with this.

```
class BankAccount(object):
def withdraw(self):
    pass
def deposit(self):
    pass
```

class SavingsAccount(BankAccount):

```
def __init__(self,  balance=500.0):
self.balance = balance

def deposit(self, deposit_amount):
self.balance += deposit_amount
  return self.balance

  if deposit_amount < 0:
    raise RuntimeError('Invalid deposit amount.')

def withdraw(self, withdraw_amount):   
self.balance -= withdraw_amount
  return self.balance

  if self.balance < 500:
    raise RuntimeError('Cannot withdraw beyond the minimum account balance')
  return self.balance

  if withdraw_amount > self.balance:
    raise RuntimeError('Cannot withdraw beyond the current account balance')
  return self.balance

  if withdraw_amount < 0:
    raise RuntimeError('Invalid withdraw amount')
```

class CurrentAmount(BankAccount):
    def **init**(self,  balance=0.0):
    self.balance = balance

```
def deposit(self,deposit_amount)
self.balance += deposit_amount
  return self.balance

  if amount < 0:
    raise RuntimeError('Invalid deposit amount.')
  return self.balance


def withdraw(self, withdraw_amount):   
   self.balance -= withdraw_amount
  return self.balance

  if withdwa_amount < 0:
    raise RuntimeError('Invalid withdraw amount')
  return self.balance

  if withdwa_amount > self.balance:
    raise RuntimeError('Cannot withdraw beyond the current account balance')
  return self.balance
```

I need a little help with the indentation error, to know what it is and how to solve it. i am new to  python

Comment: `raise RuntimeError('Invalid withdraw amount.` You're missing a closing parenthesis

Comment: and a colon after all if-statements

Comment: A lot of errors here: you can't do `def` without then indenting and writing some code (even if it's just `pass`). `if` statements also require indentation and a colon (`:`) . you're missing quotes and parantheses on your `Raise` too in more than 1 place. There is no point in `return`ing after `raise`ing because you'll never get there

Answer (score 1):

This is properly indented and logically correct code. You must read python coding guidelines before reaching for support to a community.

```
class BankAccount(object):
    def withdraw(self, withdraw_amount):
        pass

    def deposit(self, deposit_amount):
        pass


class SavingsAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self,  balance=500.0):
        self.balance = balance

    def deposit(self, deposit_amount):
        if deposit_amount < 0:
            raise RuntimeError('Invalid deposit amount.')
        self.balance += deposit_amount
        return self.balance

    def withdraw(self, withdraw_amount):
        if self.balance < 500:
            raise RuntimeError('Cannot withdraw beyond the minimum account balance')

        if withdraw_amount > self.balance:
            raise RuntimeError('Cannot withdraw beyond the current account balance')

        if withdraw_amount < 0:
            raise RuntimeError('Invalid withdraw amount.')

        self.balance -= withdraw_amount
        return self.balance


class CurrentAmount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self,  balance=0.0):
        self.balance = balance

    def deposit(self,deposit_amount):
        if deposit_amount < 0:
            raise RuntimeError('Invalid deposit amount.')

        self.balance += deposit_amount
        return self.balance

    def withdraw(self, withdraw_amount):  
        if withdraw_amount < 0:
            raise RuntimeError('Invalid withdraw amount')

        if withdraw_amount > self.balance:
         raise RuntimeError('Cannot withdraw beyond the current account balance')

        self.balance -= withdraw_amount
        return self.balance
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies with the function definitions below; you can't declare just empty functions you need to give them some kind of body.

```
class BankAccount(object):
    def withdraw(self):
        pass
    def deposit(self):
        pass
```

Also if you have directly copy-pasted your code then it looks like you're not using enough spaces to indent

i.e. if I copy paste the line

`def deposit(self):`

it only has 2 spaces before it

Answer (score 0):

Python uses indentation to indicate code blocks. You *must* be consistent in your indentation levels. Pick tabs or  a certain number of spaces and *use that everywhere*.

You also must have at least one statement where a block is expected. If you must, use a `pass` statement to do nothing.

```
class BankAccount(object):
    def withdraw(self):
        pass        # Add this

    def deposit(self):
        pass        # Add this

    def other_function(self):
        if 42 != 42:
            raise EndOfTheWorldError("what")
```

Comment: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level...what you mean is they should all have the same spacing

Comment: Look at the code I've provided. You need to indent things like the body of a class, function, or control flow statement (e.g. `if`). You're also missing the colon after some of your `if` statements.

Comment: I suggest you start with a very simple "hello world" program and add code constructs as you get more familiar. Writing a giant blob of broken code that doesn't work and then asking the Internet to fix it for you is an awful way to learn a new language.

Answer (score 0):

There are many changes required.

1. If you dont want to define methods, you can use `pass`

   def withdraw(self):
       pass
2. After every if condition, there should be colon `:`

   if self.balance < 500: